# How to make Users sort in reverse order by default?

Tags: users

I have a new site that had over 600+ users imported after the primary development was complete. All but 10 of them are "subscribers" with no admin capability. Since we admins and editors were the first users to be created, we are now at the end of the list every time we go to the Users page so it makes getting to us require alot of clicking. I'd like it to default in reverse order, so User ID 1 (me) is at the top / first upon entering the Users page right away.

Comment: What users list are you talking about here?

Comment: The WP Users list. /wp-admin/users.php

Answer (score 2):

You can override the default query arguments using `users_list_table_query_args`:

```
function wpse_214577_users_list_table_query_args( $args ) {
    if ( empty( $args['orderby'] ) )
        $args['orderby'] = 'ID';
    if ( empty( $args['order'] ) )
        $args['order'] = 'ASC';

    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'users_list_table_query_args', 'wpse_214577_users_list_table_query_args' );
```